# Words Search in a txt document, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this simple code that reads a txt file and accepts a word from the user to check if that word is in the txt document or not. It looks like this works only for a single word. I have to modify this code so that the user can input two or more words. Example; `GOING HOME` instead of just `HOME`. Any help please.

```
word = input('Enter any word that you want to find in text File :')
f = open("AM30.EB","r")
if word in f.read().split():
    print('Word Found in Text File')
else:
    print('Word not found in Text File')
```

Comment: Would you want to search for 'GOING HOME' in sequence or 'GOING' and 'HOME' separately?

Comment: @codewelldev There are three possible things it could mean -- (a) both words, (b) either word, (c) exact phrase. Which is it please, Charles?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for

```
f = open("AM30.EB","r")

word_list = []

while True:
    word = input('Enter any word that you want to find in text File or 1 to stop entering words :')
    if word == "1": break
    word_list.append(word)

file_list = f.read().split()

for word in word_list:
    if word in file_list:
        print("Found word - {}".format(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

These are case-sensitive solutions!

All words in query separately:

```
words = input('Enter all words that you want to find in text File: ').split()
f_data = []
with open("AM30.EB", "r") as f:
    f_data = f.read().split()
results = list(map(lambda x: any([y == x for y in f_data]), words))
print("Found ")
for i in range(len(words)): 
    print(f"'{words[i]}'", end="")
    if i < len(words) - 1:
        print("and", end="")
print(f": {all(results)}")
```

Any word in query:

```
words = input('Enter any word that you want to find in the text File: ').split()
f_data = []
with open("AM30.EB", "r") as f:
    f_data = f.read().split()
results = list(map(lambda x: any([y == x for y in f_data]), words))
if any(results):
    for i in range(len(words)):
        print(f"Found '{words[i]}': {results[i]}")
```

Exact phrase in query:

```
phrase = input('Enter a phrase that you want to find in the text File: ')
f_data = ""
with open("AM30.EB", "r") as f:
    f_data = f.read()
print(f"Found '{phrase}': {f_data.count(phrase) > 0}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is case sensitive and checks for each word individually. Not sure if this is what you were looking for but hope it helps!

```
file1 = open('file.txt', 'r').read().split()

wordsFoundList = []

userInput = input('Enter any word or words that you want to find in text File :').split()
for word in userInput:
    if word in file1:
        wordsFoundList.append(word)

if len(wordsFoundList) == 0:
    print("No words found in text file")
else:
    print("These words were found in text file: " + str(wordsFoundList))
```